# How to execute child packages selectively based on configuration values?

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that executes multiple child packages

```
pkg1
 |
 |
 |
pkg2
 |
 |
 |
pkg3
```

I would like to execution of the child packages configurable so that I can change which child packages to execute based on the configuration values.

Which option in SSIS would allow me to enable/disable the child package executions within the parent package?

Comment: On precedence constraint i added expression to check if the variable is set to true. But when it is set to false it just stops and doesnt go to the next task.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a Execute package task inside a Foreach loop container
and control the packages to be run through a table. As you are planning to 
run the packages serially, this pattern will work well for you.

Some details:

1. Create a new table

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActivePackages](
       [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       [PackageName] varchar NOT NULL,
       [Active] [bit] NOT NULL
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
2. Insert two rows

   ID  PackageName Active

   1   c_mp_Child1.dtsx    0

   2   c_mp_Child2.dtsx    1
3. Create a parent (p_MainPackage.dtsx) and two child packages (c_mp_Child1.dtsx and c_mp_Child2.dtsx)
4. Description of p_MainPackage.dtsx
   Variables

   sActivePackageFullPath (String)

   Expression: @[User::sSolutionFolder] + "\" +  @[User::sActivePackage]

   Evaluate As Expression: True

   sSolutionFolder String

   oActivePackages Object  System.Object

   sActivePackage  String
5. Execute SQL Task -- Get list of active projects and store in oActivePackages
6. Foreach Loop Container

   Enumerator: Foreacj ADO Enumerator
       ADO object source variables: User::oActiveProject
       Variable mapping

: User::sActivePackageFullPath
6a. Inside: Execute Package Task
        Connection String for the Child package: @[User::sActivePackageFullPath]